# How to get private methods working in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, private-members, private-methods

I have some code that looks roughly like:

```
class A {
  #hidden = 0;
  method() {
    return this.#hidden;
  }
}
```

This works fine when I use JS, but when I convert it to TS I get the error `Parsing error: Invalid character` because of the `#`. Is there any way I can enable this feature in TS? I am trying to avoid using the `private` keyword.

Comment: I don't think this is supported in typescript yet.

Comment: Here is the [Pull Request](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30829) for it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private fields are not yet supported in Typescript. There is a [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30829) on the topic that will probably make it into 3.7 or 3.8 (just an educated guess, not a member of the team, I have no insight into planning).

In the meantime you could use the old typescript `private` keyword.

```
class A {
  private hidden = 0;
  method() {
    return this.hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the current method better than the new method. Just my opinion though.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn That is a topic for a religious schism in Javascript/Typescript. I like the old way better too. But `#` is here might as well get used to it 